# passing php variable into html

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php so pardon the ignorance 
I'm trying to include a php variable, it is and is not working.

```
$currentdata = file_get_contents("http://www.abr.business.gov.au/abnDetails.aspx?abn=$abn");
```

This works with $abn being the variable being passed from earlier being set.

```
$abntypedata = '/d$abn&amp;ResultListURL=">(.+?)</'; This does not work.
$abntypedata = '/d33051775556&amp;ResultListURL=">(.+?)</'; This does.
```

I need to be able to use the variable $abn to insert that number as it will be user defined. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php is perticular about the quotations. You have to use double quotes to include variables:

```
$abntypedata = "/d$abn&amp;ResultListURL=\">(.+?)</"; This works
```

or

```
$abntypedata = '/d'.$abn.'&amp;ResultListURL=">(.+?)</'; This works
```

Comment: Great, #2 worked perfectly and I learnt something along the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Variable substitution does **not** occur with **single** quotes. Change those to **double** quotes and should work.

**EDIT:** FYI, here's the PHP manual for strings in PHP. It's useful to know what the various types of strings are: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't use inline variables like that in single-quoted strings.

```
$abntypedata = "/d$abn&amp;ResultListURL=\">(.+?)</";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Double Quotes around the string " not ' that should render the variables other wise do this:

```
$abntypedata = '/d'.$abn.'&amp;ResultListURL=">(.+?)</';
```